# "Expression resolves to an unused l-value" vs "Expression is unused"

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, lvalue

Consider the following code:

```
class Foo {
    let bar = "Hello world!"
    init () {
        self // Warning: Expression of type 'Foo' is unused
        self.bar // Error: Expression resolves to an unused l-value
    }
    func test () {
        self.bar // Warning: Expression of type 'String' is unused
    }
}
```

Why are the messages different, and why is only one an error?  I understand what they mean, I just don't get why the compiler handles them differently.

Comment: @Hamish Regarding your last comment, isn't that only the case when it hasn't already been assigned a value though?

Comment: @Hamish So if I'm reading that right, it's just a limitation of the compiler not checking for already-intialized `let`s when checking l-values?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the complier treated `self.bar` as l-value in the initializer since during initialization **you can assign a value to a constant property at any point during initialization** even if you have declare it as a constant , so the compiler will treat that as an error since there is a chance to modify the constant ...

While `self.bar` in `test()` function was treated as r-value since the property is declared as constant and the compiler know that you can't modify it so there is no error will be generated and it will be treated as r-value and the return value is unused..

If you need better understanding try to change your property to a variable instead of constant and you will find that even the `self.bar` statement in the `test()` method will make an error, since the complier guess that this value also can be a left value.

```
class Foo {
    var bar = "Hello world!"
    init () {
        self // Warning: Expression of type 'Foo' is unused
        self.bar  // Error: Expression resolves to an unused l-value
    }
    func test () {
        self.bar // Changed to : Error: Expression resolves to an unused l-value
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right about what happens when I change it to `var`, I hadn't considered that and it explains it somewhat.  But when I try to assign it as a `let` in the initializer, I get "Immutable value 'self.bar' may only be initialized once," so that part doesn't make sense unless for some reason the compiler isn't figuring out that it's already been initialized in my original case.

Comment: Yes you're right, and i think maybe the complier will check l-values before checking if the stored properties are initialized or already initialized with initial values! maybe when all things goes right and before finishing initialization the compiler want to check if all stored properties are set so here will catch that the property is already assigned an initial value ...

Answer (score 0):

The difference in diagnostic is due to the difference in whether the expression is treated as an lvalue or an rvalue by the compiler. These are internal compiler terms that shouldn't need to be known by the user, but essentially an lvalue is primarily used to represent a mutable expression – that is, an expression which can be assigned to using `=` or passed `inout`. An lvalue consists of components, for example the expression `a.b[]` can be represented as an lvalue with the variable base `a`, member access component `.b` and subscript component `[]`.

An lvalue can be *loaded* to produce an rvalue, which is more commonly just called a value, and is immutable. For example, making the function call `foo(a.b[])` would require the lvalue `a.b[]` to be loaded in order to be passed as an argument.

You get an error for an unused lvalue due to the fact that it's ambiguous whether you want the compiler to perform a load (which can trigger side effects, such as a call to a variable getter), or whether you meant to store a value but haven't written the `= ...` yet (which wouldn't call a getter). You only get a warning for an unused rvalue due to the fact that it's not ambiguous.

Okay, so let's talk about each of the examples you raise:

```
class Foo {
  let bar = "Hello world!"
  func test () {
    self.bar // Warning: Expression of type 'String' is unused
  }
}
```

`self.bar` here is treated as an rvalue because it's an immutable expression due to the property `bar` being a constant that has already been initialised.

---

```
class Foo {
  init () {
    self // Warning: Expression of type 'Foo' is unused
  }
}
```

`self` here is treated as an rvalue because `self` is immutable within the body of a class declaration.

---

Okay, now onto the interesting one:

```
class Foo {
  let bar = "Hello world!"
  init () {
    self.bar // Error: Expression resolves to an unused l-value
  }
}
```

<sup>(note that this diagnostic was recently improved by [#14227](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/14227))</sup>

`self.bar` here is treated as an lvalue, despite being immutable. Remember above when I said that an lvalue is *primarily* used to represent a mutable expression? Well, as it turns out, they can also be used to represent immutable expressions that fit the lvalue model (that is, expressions that can be modelled using lvalue components, such as `self.bar`).

So why exactly is `self.bar` being treated as an lvalue here? Turns out [it is in order to avoid triggering a load of the base expression](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/33fc37d8312101869728080d3f19e5f06da453c3) `self`, which would count as a read of `self` and therefore render the following code invalid:

```
struct S { 
  let x: Int = 1
  let y: Int

  init() {
    self.y = self.x 
  } 
}
```

due to the fact that `self.x` would perform a load of `self` before it's fully initialised if it were treated as an rvalue.

By being treated as an lvalue, DefiniteInitialization (the compiler pass that diagnoses invalid initialisations) is able to recognise that `self.x` is a read of an already-initialised property and therefore allow the code to compile. But that being said, there's no real reason why DefiniteInitialization couldn't recognise the pattern of `self` being loaded followed by a member access of an already-initialised property. Ultimately, `self.x` being treated as an lvalue here is an implementation detail.